# Event not reaching the parent component from child component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I am trying to build a very simple app and using data/event binding to transfer information between the component - I am following udemy course to learn angular and a part of that course is implementing the following :

**recipe-item** ----*child of-*----> **recipe-list** -----*child of* -----> **recipes**

- **recipe-item** captures the **click** event which is bound to **OnSelected**() in recipe-list .
- **recipe-list** emits a custom event **recipeSelected** but is not caught i.e a function **SetSelectedRecipe** in **recipes-component** which is bound to the event is not getting called.

recipes-component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <rb-recipe-list (recipeSelected) = "SetSelectedRecipe($event)"></rb-recipe-list>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <rb-recipe-detail [selectedRecipe]="selectedRecipe" ></rb-recipe-detail>
</div>
```

recipes-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit , Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe'

@Component({
  selector: 'rb-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html'
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
    @Input()    selectedRecipe: Recipe;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
  }

  SetSelectedRecipe(recipe : Recipe)
  {
    alert("The event binding is working") // not seeing this alert
    this.selectedRecipe  = recipe;
  }

}
```

recipe-list-component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <rb-recipe-item [recipe] ="recipe" (click)="OnSelected(recipe)"></rb-recipe-item>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

recipe-list-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from '../recipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'rb-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html'
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {

    recipes: Recipe[] = []
    recipe = new Recipe('Test Recipe', 'This description is extremely deceptive ', 'http://www.goodtherapy.org/admin/includes/ckfinder/userfiles/images/empty-seaside-bench.jpg')

    @Output() recipeSelected : EventEmitter<Recipe> =  new EventEmitter<Recipe>()

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  OnSelected(recipe: Recipe) {
    console.log("recipe clicked" + this.recipe.name) // seeing this log
    this.recipeSelected.emit(recipe);

  }
}
```

I am seeing the log for event click on recipe-item i.e OnSelected(recipe: Recipe) is getting called in recipe-list-component

I am not seeing the alert in recipes-component.

Any ideas?? LEt me know if you have any questions about my question?

Thanks

EDIT : I figured out the problem :

There was an issue with app.module.ts I added components to bootstrap which i shouldn't have.
So I changed the file from

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,
              HeaderComponent,
              RecipesComponent,
              RecipeDetailComponent,
              RecipeListComponent,
              RecipeItemComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

to

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and the events are getting propagated. However I do not know why this change solves the problem.

Comment: You don#t get any errors in the console? The code looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr demonstrating your issue?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't get any error in the console. just nothing happens

Comment: @BoyanKostadinov I have never plunkr-ed anything yet, I am new to javascript/typescript. But let me try doing that.

Comment: I am trying to create a plunk based on the code you provided so I can help you. So far, I haven't gotten it to work.

Comment: Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template. Just use the `[new|v]` button and choose `Angular2 (TS)`. (you can rename files by double-clicking the name.)

Comment: Was a Plunker ever created? I am having a similar issue

Comment: @HGB No I did not. i figured out what the problem was. See after EDit int he post. I talk about the solution.